# boost multi_index reverse iterator erase trouble

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-multi-index

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using Container = boost::multi_index_container<
    std::string,
    bmi::indexed_by< bmi::ordered_non_unique< bmi::identity<std::string> > >
>;

/// Get the base of a non-reverse iterator. It's the iterator itself.
inline
Container::iterator const&
iter_base(Container::iterator const& it)
{
    return it;
}

/** Get a non-reverse iterator that points at the same element as the given reverse_iterator.
 *
 * @param rit reverse_iterator
 * @return a (non-reverse) iterator that points to the same element.
 * @pre @p rit is dereferenceable (not equal to @c rend() of whatever container @p rit came from)
 */
inline
Container::iterator
iter_base(Container::reverse_iterator const& rit)
{
    auto bit = rit.base();
    // if 'rit' is a reverse iterator: &*(rit.base() - 1) == &*rit
    return --bit;
}

template <typename IT>
void evict(Container& c, IT rb, IT fin)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (; rb != fin; ) {
        if (rb->size() == 3) {
            auto victim = rb;
            ++rb;
            std::cout << "victim->" << *victim << ", next->" << (rb==fin ? std::string{"THE END"} : *rb) << "\n";
            auto next = c.erase(iter_base(victim));
            std::cout << "size=" << c.size() << "\n";
            for (auto const& s : c) {
                std::cout << "remain: " << s << "\n"; // bar - baz - foo
            }

            rb = IT(next);
            (void)next;
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(*rb);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**)
{
    bool forward = (argc == 1);

    Container c;
    c.insert("foo"); // will be last
    c.insert("bar");
    c.insert("baz");

    if (forward) {
        auto b = c.lower_bound("baz");

        std::cout << ">> " << *b << "\n"; // prints baz

        auto rb = (b);
        std::cout << "<< " << *rb            << "\n"; // prints baz
        std::cout << "<< " << *iter_base(rb) << "\n"; // prints baz

        evict(c, rb, c.end());
    }
    else {
        auto b = c.upper_bound("baz");

        std::cout << ">> " << *b << "\n"; // prints foo

        auto rb = Container::reverse_iterator(b);
        std::cout << "<< " << *rb            << "\n"; // prints baz
        std::cout << "<< " << *iter_base(rb) << "\n"; // prints baz

        evict(c, rb, c.rend());
    }
}
```

The real code does more than just erase, but this is enough to illustrate the behavior.

EDITED to show that no just removal happens in the loop.
Items are supposed to be added to `result` in forward or reverse order depending on which kind of iterator was used.

When run without arguments, `forward==true` and the output is as expected:

```
>> baz
<< baz
<< baz
victim->baz, next->foo
size=2
remain: bar
remain: foo
victim->foo, next->THE END
size=1
remain: bar
```

When run with an argument, `forward==false` and the output is:

```
>> foo
<< baz
<< baz
victim->baz, next->bar
size=2
remain: bar
remain: foo
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

(not as expected)

Compiling with address sanitizer shows a heap-use-after-free in line 42 (the ++rb line).

It seems that calling `erase(victim)` has invalidated `rb` somehow, even though erase is not supposed to invalidate any other iterator.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second answer, with the additional request from OP that traversal be done in direct or reverse order according to the nature of the iterator. With a little care this can be done like this:

```
template <typename IT>
void evict(Container& c, IT rb, IT fin)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    if(rb != fin) for(;;) {
        IT next = rb;
        ++next;
        bool finished  = (next == fin);
        if (rb->size() == 3) {
            c.erase(iter_base(rb));
            std::cout << "size=" << c.size() << "\n";
            for (auto const& s : c) {
                std::cout << "remain: " << s << "\n"; // bar - baz - foo
            }
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(*rb);
        }
        if(finished) break;
        rb = next;
    }
}
```

My bad, the stricken through code was still running into UB. Please try this:

```
template <typename IT>
void evict(Container& c, IT rb, IT fin)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    if(rb != fin) for(;;) {
        bool finished  = (std::next(rb) == fin);
        if (rb->size() == 3) {
            rb = IT{c.erase(iter_base(rb))};
            std::cout << "size=" << c.size() << "\n";
            for (auto const& s : c) {
                std::cout << "remain: " << s << "\n"; // bar - baz - foo
            }

        }
        else {
            result.push_back(*rb);
        }
        if(finished) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. The heap-use-after-free remains (in the `++next` line).

Comment: Have you directly copied the proposed code *verbatim*? Note for instance the `if(rb != fin) for(;;)` part.

Comment: Sorry, the solution proposed was indeed faulty. Edited with a hopefully correct alternative.

Comment: Still not working for me. Crashes in rebalance_for_erase

Answer (score 2):

OK, dealing with reverse iterators is a pain in the neck. Let's analyze the pointer business during the execution of this portion of the code of `evict`:

```
auto victim = rb;
++rb;
auto next = c.erase(iter_base(victim));
```

when inside the call to `evict(c,  Container::reverse_iterator(c.upper_bound("baz")), c.rend())`. By "points to" I mean "the internal iterator points to". Step by step we have:

1. Before entering the code: `rb` points to `"foo"`, `victim` does not exist yet.

   `auto victim = rb;`
2. `rb` points to `"foo"`, `victim` points to `"foo"`.

   `++rb;`
3. `rb` points to `"baz"`, `victim` points to `"foo"`.

   `auto next = c.erase(iter_base(victim));`
4. `"baz"` is erased, `rb` points to **deleted** `"baz"`, `victim` points to `"foo"`. Any further dereference, comparison or (de/in)crementing operation with `rb` is undefined behavior.

I understand you are trying to write an `evict` function that works with both iterators and reverse iterators. One potential way to do it is as follows:

```
template<typename Container>
std::pair<typename Container::iterator,typename Container::iterator>
direct_range(
  typename Container::iterator first,
  typename Container::iterator last)
{
  return {first,last};
}

template<typename Container>
std::pair<typename Container::iterator,typename Container::iterator>
direct_range(
  typename Container::reverse_iterator first,
  typename Container::reverse_iterator last)
{
  return {last.base(),first.base()};
}

template <typename IT>
void evict(Container& c, IT rb, IT fin)
{
  auto p=direct_range<Container>(rb,fin);
  c.erase(p.first,p.second);

  for(auto const& s:c){
    std::cout<<"remain: "<<s<<"\n"; // bar - baz - foo
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the actual code is not simple enough to use `erase(iterator, iterator)` (imagine if you will, that only some elements are to be erased).

Comment: You wrote "4. baz is erased". Is this because `iter_base(victim)` - an iterator - points to the same element as `rb` - a reverse iterator - ?

Comment: To your first reply: once you have the result of `direct_range`, you can replace `erase(iterator,iterator)` with more elaborate code working on non-reverse iterators.

Comment: To your second reply: yes.

Comment: I edited the loop in `evict` to show that not just removal happens in the loop. It seems to me that I can't use `direct_range` in this case (iterating over `direct_range` would always process elements on forward order - it would fill the vector in the wrong order when called with reverse_iterators).